# Derivative of $\frac{d}{dx}\ln (x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Show that $\frac{d}{dx}\ln (x+\sqrt{x^2+1}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

So I've done this so far:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln (x+\sqrt{x^2+1}) = \frac{1+x(x^2+1)^{-0.5}}{x+(x^2+1)^{0.5}}$$

I have tried a few combinations but cannot attain the desired result. Could someone offer just a hint to get me going?

Thanks

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x^2+1}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your differentiation *is* correct, and you applied the chain rule correctly. But as you note, your result *can* be simplified.

Let's rewrite the fraction, expressing the term $x(x^2 + 1)^{-0.5}$ in the numerator as $\frac{x}{\sqrt {x^2 + 1}}$, then simply multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$:

$$\begin{align}\frac{1+x(x^2+1)^{-0.5}}{x+(x^2+1)^{0.5}} & = \frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}\\ \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 +1} + x}{{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\sqrt{x^2+1}}}\\ \\
& =\frac{\color{blue}{\bf x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{(\color{blue}{\bf x+\sqrt{x^2+1}})\sqrt{x^2+1}} \\ \\
& =\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\end{align}$$

Comment: This needs a TU! +1

Comment: @amwhy thanks once again haha

Comment: You're welcome, @salman!

Answer (score 5):

Recognize the function $\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$ as the [inverse hyperbolic sine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function), $\text{arcsinh } x$. According to the inverse function theorem we have

$$\frac{d}{dx} \text{arcsinh } x=\frac{1}{\cosh \text{arcsinh }x}=\frac{1}{\dfrac{e^{\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}+e^{-(\ln{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}})}}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}. $$

Answer (score 4):

Using [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) of derivative , $$\frac{d(\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}))}{dx}=\frac{d(\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}))}{d(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}\frac{d(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}{dx}$$

$$=\frac1{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}\left(1+\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: amazing method.

Comment: @salman,you did not ask, I have tried to show how the answer has come

Comment: I think salman applied the chain rule quite well (and didn't need to be shown that)... just needed some algebraic manipulation to turn the correct result into the simplified correct result.

Comment: @amWhy,have you noticed salman's comment?